# Are cv::viz::Widget clickable? (OpenCV C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I've seen that there can be [an event handler for mouse click in viz](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d3b/classcv_1_1viz_1_1MouseEvent.html), but not an equivalent for the [Widget](http://cartucho.github.io/d7/dcd/classcv_1_1viz_1_1Widget.html).

Is there any way to use the `Point` returned from `viz::MouseEvent()` to detect a click on a widget?

Answer (score 0):

No, Widgets are not clickable.

You can:

1. get an MouseEvent
2. check the click checking if type == MouseButtonPress
3. get the Point in window where click happened
4. use converTo3DRay to get a ray representing click's all depths in 3D
5. iterate your widgets looking for intersection.  Intersection is computed differently in each king of widget.

getWidgetPose gives you the pose in reference to the camera.  getWidgetPose(...).translation() gives you the place the widget is.  If you aren't comfortable with this translation, you can apply converTo3DRay.

If you find many widgets, you can order by z coordinate (the lower, the closer to camera).  It works for points, it's harder for other geomtry.